# Convert Sony Vaio F Series to Ubuntu? Or dual boot?

Tags: dual-boot, vaio, sony

I have a Vaio, model number VPCF234FD, and I'd really love to dual boot it. But I've seen that many people have trouble dual-booting their Vaios. Does anyone have experience with an F Series Vaio?

Secondly, if it's not possible to dual boot, could I just replace Windows altogether? Would that work better? Once Windows 7 support ends I'm not really interested in spending money to upgrade. So, has anyone tried replacing Windows on a Vaio?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I'm pleased to report that I have successfully dual booted my VPCF234FD Sony Vaio F Series laptop. The installation went off without a hitch, Grub loads normally and all is well. Hooray. In case anyone is curious I did it via DVD, not USB. 14.04 LTS, 64-bit, of course.